# How to find iOS application bugs due to deprecated code?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiimagepickercontroller, assets

After selecting a video from the Photo Library I obtained the NSURL of the video with `info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL]`.

```
    if let selectedVideo = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as? NSURL, let videoURLString = selectedVideo.absoluteString {
        print(videoURLString) // print unwrapped url as string
        videoView.configure(url: videoURLString)
        videoView.isLoop = true
        videoView.play()
    } else {
        print("Error in unwrapping selected video as a local file URL!")
    }
```

I properly unwrapped it and configured my UIView to play after passing the String.  Here is the configure function of videoView.

```
    func configure(url: String) {
    if let videoURL = URL(string: url) {
        player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL)
        playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
        playerLayer?.frame = bounds
        playerLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resize
        if let playerLayer = self.playerLayer {
            layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
        }
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(reachTheEndOfTheVideo(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: self.player?.currentItem)
    }
}
```

This worked just fine in simulator on an iPhone 8 Plus, but after running on my own iPhone 8 Plus, the UIView that would play the video was not loading,  nor was I getting an error message.  I later realized that `UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL` was deprecated as of iOS 11.0 even though documentation does state it should be supported iOS 4.1+.  [image]

I used `UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL` instead and *then* it finally worked on my phone as well as the simulator.

I did not receive an error either times and `print(videoURLString)` was properly printing the asset URL.  To find this took quite sometime.  How can I better guard the application against bugs like this when troubleshooting?  If I cannot use optional binding, how else can I print an error for these kinds of bugs?

Comment: Has nothing to do with it being deprecated, `AVPlayer` just can't load asset library URLs